# Confirm Modal issue when remove a product from cart

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hi i am facing an issue while trying to remove a product from cart, i made a function to only delete the product if the customer click accept on the confirm modal, everything works fine until there are two or more products, if i click accept on one product then the others products didn't display the confirm modal when click and they are removing instantly.
There is my function, thanks in advance.

```
const productsButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");

function removeProductButton() {
for (let i = 0; i < productsButtons.length; i++) {
productsButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (
    e.target.dataset.product_id ===
    productsButtons[i].getAttribute("data-product_id")
  ) {
    if (!confirm("You want to delete this product?")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
 });
}
}

removeProductButton();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working.

```js
const productsButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");

function removeProductButton() {
  for (let i = 0; i < productsButtons.length; i++) {
    productsButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (
        e.target.dataset.product_id ===
        productsButtons[i].getAttribute("data-product_id")
      ) {
        if (!confirm("You want to delete this product?")) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
          e.target.remove();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

removeProductButton();
```

```html
<button class="remove" data-product_id="1">remove 1</button>
<button class="remove" data-product_id="2">remove 2</button>
<button class="remove" data-product_id="3">remove 3</button>
```